# selenium webscraping not working on linux server

Tags: linux, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, server, selenium-chromedriver

I've developed a headless scraper using Selenium, which runs perfectly on my MacBook without the need for Chromedriver, as it seems Selenium alone suffices for local execution. The scraper performs its intended functions without any issues when executed locally.

However, when I attempt to deploy and run the same script on my server, which is running Ubuntu (Linux), I encounter errors that prevent the scraper from executing as expected. I've ensured that the Selenium version is consistent across both my local and server environments to avoid compatibility issues.

Development Environment:

- Local: MacBook, Selenium installed (no Chromedriver)
- Server: Ubuntu (Linux), same version of Selenium as local

Problem:
Upon running the script on the server, it fails to execute, throwing errors that didn't occur during local development.

Attempted Solutions:

- ```
    Verified that Selenium versions match on both local and server environments.
  ```
- ```
    Checked for missing dependencies specific to the Ubuntu server that might be          required for headless scraping.
  ```

Errors:

```
`File "/app/apps/dashboards/management/commands/scrape.py", line 9, in handle
    NewsFetcher().fetch_articles()
  File "/app/apps/dashboards/external/redacted.py", line 126, in fetch_articles
    self.initialize_driver()
  File "/app/apps/dashboards/external/redacted.py", line 39, in initialize_driver
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in           __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 115, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/121.0.6167.85/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status            code was: 127`
```

Question:
What could be causing the headless scraper to work locally on my MacBook but fail on the Ubuntu server? Are there additional configurations or dependencies required for Selenium to run headless scrapers on Linux-based servers?
Any insights or suggestions to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I tried matching the same selenium versions, I tried installing google chrome on the server, I tried installing the chromedriver version 114.

specificly I checked where the chromedriver was installed and then defined the location to it

so I found where the chromedriver was installed on my server and then set:
Service(the/path/to/my/chromdriverfile)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt install chromium-chromedriver
```